# CSS sections line divide

Tags: css, sections

I would like to be able to separate my website into sections with a line. An example at what I am looking to create is on this website right under the pic of Napoleon http://www.napoleon-bonaparte-brownsville.com/
[Napoleon](http://www.napoleon-bonaparte-brownsville.com/)
[Napoleon website](http://www.napoleon-bonaparte-brownsville.com/)

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? SO is not a code writing service, but we are glad to help you out with a problem

Comment: It sounds pretty simple what you are trying to achieve you could use a border-bottom property on a class where you want the line to appear or maybe a <hr> tag. Hard to know what would be best without a code example.

Comment: <hr> Can you give some more information?

Comment: That <hr> worked. I did not find anything on the internet about that particular line of code so I was trying to do a padded box with a underline that was a certain # of pixels below the word lol.

Comment: When you see something on a webpage that you want to emulate, "view page source" is your friend :)

Comment: A simple _"Inspect Element"_ on the napoleon page clearly showed it is a `border-top: 4px solid #222222`

Comment: Stephen may I ask what browser you happen to be using.

Comment: Tom Zych used I used CTRL +f to look for anywhere in the source code that said border and found 1 spot wich was completely unrelated to what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html, you can add a horizontal line with the `<hr>` tag. In css, you could create a line with the border of elements (ex. `.borderLeft { border-left: thick double #ff0000;}` creates a double red line on the left of borderLeft class elements)